# Kafka:Have to get middle of message ranges from broker to consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

Let say producer generate 10 message and it will stored in broker.If I want to access particularly  6 and 7 message how I can get from consumer client.
please tell me any one on which way I have to approach this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to read the full stream and use a filter to get what you are interested in. Example to get only even numbered data from kafka, using spark.

```
JavaRDD<String> filter = input.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            int i = 0;
            @Override
            public Boolean call(String v1) throws Exception {
                return i++ % 2 == 0;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm not aware of spark .There is any way  to get offsets  from broker  based on time ranges ? let say I want offsets between 7 a.m to 8 a.m for a topic.

Comment: Refer the Kafka FAQ "How do I accurately get offsets of messages for a certain timestamp using OffsetRequest?"  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIaccuratelygetoffsetsofmessagesforacertaintimestampusingOffsetRequest?

Comment: I set that parameter but how can I get that offset log ?and it is not visible while opening that log I mean to say encrypted formatted

Comment: I can able to generate logs based on the specific  time  and It is possible to convert /tmp/kafka-logs/topic/*.log file into visible format.